Seeking General Solution for Nonlinear ODE Without Initial Conditions
I am working on solving the following nonlinear second-order ordinary differential equation (ODE):
\begin{equation}
f''(x) + f'(x) f''(x) + x f'(x) - f(x) = 0
\end{equation}
I am looking for a solution that is valid for all real numbers $x$. Therefore, I am not considering initial conditions or boundary conditions in the solution process.

I attempted to solve it by using a substitution method where I let $g(x) = f'(x)$. This reduced the original ODE to a first-order ODE for $g(x)$:
\begin{equation}
g'(x) + g(x) g'(x) + x g(x) - f(x) = 0
\end{equation}
However, solving this reduced equation is still quite challenging, and I was unable to find an explicit solution for $f(x)$.
Here is what I did:


Substituted $g(x) = f'(x)$ into the original ODE.
This led to a first-order nonlinear ODE in terms of $g(x)$.
I attempted to solve this first-order ODE, but the complexity remains high.

Is there an alternative method, or further simplification, that could lead to an explicit solution for this ODE? Additionally, are there numerical methods or other analytical techniques that might be more suitable for solving such a nonlinear ODE? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

As you can write the main part of the terms as a first derivative, and an incompatible term remains
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[f'(x)+\tfrac12f'(x)^2+xf(x)]-2f(x)=0,
$$
further symbolic simplification appears unlikely.
This is the natural state for general ODE, there is no symbolic simplification or even solution to be expected.

I'm not sure whether Frobenius' power series form,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n,$$
applies or whether it rather applies
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^{n+\alpha}$$
or some other mutant variation, but using the first version we reduce the ODE to
$$\small\sum_{n\geq 0}\left\{(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+\left(\sum_{j\geq 0}^n(n+1-j)(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}a_{n+1-j}\right)+(n-1)a_{n}\right\}x^{n}=0$$
If we let $a_0$ and $a_1$ be arbitrary constants that depend on the initial conditions, $f(0)\equiv a_0$ and $f'(0)\equiv a_1$, we may then impose the coefficient to be $0$ $\forall n$. That being, for $n=0$ we have
$$2a_2+2a_2a_1-a_0=0\implies a_2=\dfrac{a_0}{2(1+a_1)},$$
for $n=1$
$$6a_3+4a_2+6a_3a_1=0\implies a_3=-\dfrac{a_0^2}{6(1+a_1)^3}$$
for $n=2$
$$12a_4+18a_3a_2+12a_4a_1+a_2=0\implies a_4=-\dfrac{3a_0^3+a_0(1+a_1)^3}{24(1+a_1)^5},$$
and so on.
Note that the mixed coefficients sum runs through $a_2a_{n+1}$ to $a_{n+2}a_1$. Moreover, we've seen that coefficients $a_2$ and above can factor at least an $a_0$ term, meaning, in turn, that if $a_0=0$ then we get the trivial solution @KevinDietrich was insinuating, namely,
$$f(x)=a_1x.$$
In addition, we also observed how all coefficients depend on $a_0$ and $1+a_1$, hence, in the case $a_1=0$, then the solution should look somewhat like
$$f(x)=a_0\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\mathcal O(x^3)\right)$$
The reason why coefficients depend on $1+a_1$ and not $a_1$ is because only the marked terms in the recurrence relation include $a_{n+2}$ terms:
$$\small\color{red}{(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}}+\left(\sum_{j\geq 0}^{\color{red}{n}}(n+1-j)(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}a_{n+1-j}\right)+(n-1)a_{n}=0.$$
Thusly,
$$\small\color{red}{(n+2)(n+1)(1+a_1)a_{n+2}}+\left(\sum_{j\geq 0}^{n-1}(n+1-j)(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}a_{n+1-j}\right)+(n-1)a_{n}=0$$
so it follows
$$\small a_{n+2}=-\dfrac{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{j\geq 0}^{n-1}(n+1-j)(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}a_{n+1-j}\right)+(n-1)a_{n}}{(n+2)(n+1)(1+a_1)},\enspace (\text{for } n=0\text{ the sum is just } 0)$$
which is the pattern we've been observing.

\begin{align}
(1+f')f''+xf'-f=0.
\end{align}
We can find a solution subject to the veracity of a proposed solution.
Using the contact transformation $f=(X-1)Y'_X-Y$, $x=Y'_X$, which implies $f'=X-1$ and $f''=1/Y''_{XX}$, we arrive at the Emden-Fowler equation
\begin{align}
YY''_{XX}=X.
\end{align}
Emden-Fowler equations are generalized-homogeneous and thus can be reduced by one order; let $Y=X^{3/2}z(\xi)/2$, $X=\exp\xi$ to get
\begin{align}
\frac z2\left(\frac{z''_{\xi\xi}}{2}+\frac{z'_\xi}{2}+\frac z8\right)+1=0.
\end{align}
Taking $z'_\xi=-p(z)$ we have an Abel equation of the second kind in canonical form
\begin{align}
pp'_z-p=-\frac14z-\frac4z.
\end{align}
The Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations does not have a nice solution for this particular case. There is a solution proposed in this paper to which they show numerically follows previously known cases. We will take this solution at face value here, but the argument following would work if the solution were different. The solution stated is of the form
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{2p}{z+C}-\frac13\right)^3+3\varphi(z,C)\left(\frac{2p}{z+C}-\frac13\right)+2\psi(z,C)=0,
\end{align}
for very nonlinear functions $\phi$  and $\psi$ which you can find in the paper if you are interested. The paper presents this in a bit of a convoluted manner, but when you combine their equations you arrive at what I've written here. This equation is cubic in $p$ ($=-z'_\xi$) and can be solved as
\begin{align}
z'_\xi=-\frac{z+C}{2}\left(\frac13+\sqrt[3]{-\psi+\sqrt{\psi^2+\phi^3}}+\sqrt[3]{-\psi-\sqrt{\psi^2+\phi^3}}\right)\equiv\Psi(z,C),
\end{align}
which is separable,
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm dz}{\Psi(z,C)}=\xi+C_2.
\end{align}
After some manipulation we find the parametric solution
\begin{align}
f=(X-1)\left(\frac{3Y}{2X}+\frac{X^{1/2}}{2}\Psi(2X^{3/2}Y,C)\right)-Y,\quad 
x=\frac{3Y}{2X}+\frac{X^{1/2}}{2}\Psi(2X^{3/2}Y,C),\quad \int \frac{\mathrm d(2X^{-3/2}Y)}{\Psi(2X^{-3/2}Y,C)}=\log X+C_2,
\end{align}
which is quite the long way to say that you should numerically approximate it!
